# Run multiple instances of a python application using kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes

Kubernetes version: Latest
Cloud being used: bare metal
Host OS: Ubuntu 16.04

I am a newbie to kubernetes so if responses are a little detailed it would be highly appreciated.

My objective is to run multiple instances of a python application. Each instance will be passed with static number of arguments (5 arguments). Each instance will basically run ffmpeg decoding in GPU and generate kakfa streams. Trigger to create a new instance will come on socket.io.

I would like to manage the process state, maintain separate logs (log file name would be an argument). Would also like to seek help on how to start and stop the process. Would require help on how to achieve this.

This is my first post so please be patient if any guidelines have not been followed.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :) Which of these steps do you have issues with? If you want to know several things (e.g. how to run a Python application in Kubernetes, how to pass arguments and how to save application logs), it might be better to create separate questions for that.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I need to know how to run a Python application in Kubernetes. How to manage the process state and how to start and stop the process

Comment: There are a lot of guides on how to run a python application in Kubernetes, basically you could just google "run a python application in kubernetes". Just an example - https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/23/get-started-with-kubernetes-using-python/ 
So I would start with containerizing your application and deploying it. The problem is that your question is actually several questions that are hard to answer without being familiar with the application. An example of a "good" question would be: "I have an application running in Kubernetes, how can I terminate it when an event A happens?"

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I think this is what I wanted.